# Cannot enter text in html input control in safari browser of ipad mini

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari

I created a login control using html and asp.net as below

```
<div id="login_Background" style="width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;background-color:#000;z-index:1000;LEFT:27%;">
        <div id="loginModal" class="container" >
            <h3>
                Login</h3>
            <div>
                <label id="login_warning" runat="server"></label>
                <input id="login_txtUsername" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                <input id="login_txtPassword" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Password" />    
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enter" CssClass="button_login" OnClick="login_btnLogin_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The issue i am facing is I cannot enter anything in the textboxes either in safari for ipad or in google chrome for ipad,even the keyboard is not showing in ipad. I checked this in google chrome in my windows pc and it is working fine.Any idea for resolving this

Comment: Any link to your site?

Comment: no it is not hosted in public server

Comment: nothing wrong with your code their. i dont know in your local machine. hahaha